# The String should not accept numbers and starting and ending index values should not accept negative numbers, but it does

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Module2{

```
Scanner reader;
String inputString;
int startIndex;
int endIndex;
```

public Module2(){

```
reader=null;
inputString="";
startIndex=-1;
endIndex=-1;
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creating new Module2 Object using the constructor from a
    Module2 obj = new Module2();

    System.out.println("Starting Application");

    String firstinput = obj.getinputString("Please enter your name");
    System.out.println(firstinput);

    String secondinput = obj.getinputStart("Please enter a starting index value");
    System.out.println(secondinput);

    String thirdinput = obj.getinputEnd("Please enter a ending index value");
    System.out.println(thirdinput);


    System.out.println("Ending Application");



}
String getinputString(String first) {
    System.out.println(first);
    reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = reader.nextLine();  
    first = input;
    return "Thank you.";

}

String getinputStart(String first) {
    System.out.println(first);
    reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = reader.nextInt();  
    startIndex = input;
    return "Thank you.";
}

String getinputEnd(String first) {
    System.out.println(first);
    reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = reader.nextInt();  
    endIndex = input;
    return "Thank You";


}
```

The Output(How is it and should work):

Staring application

Please enter your name:
Harshal
"Thank you"

Please enter your starting index value: 
1
"Thank you"

Please enter your ending index value: 
1
"Thank you"

Ending Application

How it also works when it should not:
Staring application

Please enter your name:
3
"Thank you"

Please enter your starting index value: 
-1
"Thank you"

Please enter your ending index value: 
-3
"Thank you"

Ending Application

Comment: And what is actually your question? Also, format your code properly, there's a button for that.

Answer (score 0):

**To check if the name only contains spaces:**

```
public static boolean onlyLettersSpaces(String s){
  for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(ch) || ch == ' ') {
     continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**If you want to check if the number is negative**

```
boolean isPositive(int number) {
  if (number < 0) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Use a while loop to go back and ask the same question if it's a wrong answer, or make te user restart the program itself.

Comment: your isNegative method returns false for negative numbers.

Comment: @Janar Noticed the mistake :). Changed the function to isPositive();